# Como posso selecionar dados únicos em SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Olá gostaria de saber como posso selecionar dados únicos em SQL?
tenho uma planilha do Excel que possui os daods que preciso extrair uma informação aplicando o seguinte filtro em sql:

- **GSM** que não se repetir (ou seja, que for único), e que tenha o **STATUS** = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'

Tentei com o DISTINCT:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT [GSM], [MOTIVO_ENVIO], [STATUS]
FROM export WHERE [STATUS] = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'
```

Mas isso não resolve meu problema, pois o DISTINCT por exemplo se tiver 5 dados repetidos ele trará somente 1 desses 5, e não é isso que preciso, preciso somente dos **GSM** que não se repetem mesmo, ou seja que forem únicos.

Tentei também usando GROUP BY, HAVING:

```sql
select gsm, status from export
where status = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'
group by 1, 2
having count(gsm) = 1
order by 1;
```

Mas não me retorna do jeito que preciso, alguém poderia me ajudar?

> Exemplo:

[image: Filtros únicos]

No exemplo acima, tenho alguns dados, dentre eles os que preciso estão em em negrito e sublinhado, porque o GSM deles são únicos (não se repetem) e tem o STATUS = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'

> Irei por aqui a criação dessa tabela, e alguns dados para ter como testar:

```sql
create table export (
  gsm bigint,
  status varchar
);

insert into export values
('3154321575', 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'),
('3154321575', 'PENDENTE'),
('3101234567', 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'),
('2198465289', 'PENDENTE'),
('3274185296', 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'),
('3274185296', 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'),
('3274185296', 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'),
('3140028926', 'LIBERADO'),
('3140028926', 'PENDENTE'),
('3176543210', 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA');
```

Comment: @Bacco editei a tag, obrigado, então eu tentei reproduzir o que precisava e me retornar ainda alguns GSM duplicados, preciso SOMENTE dos que forem únicos e que tenha STATUS = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA' a nova query ficou assim:

select gsm, status from export where status = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA' group by 1, 2 having count(gsm) > 1 order by 1;

Mas aconteceu que ela pegou alguns GSM duplicados que tenha em ambos o STATUS = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA' e isso não pode acontecer, poderia me ajudar amigo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT EX.GSM, EX.MOTIVO_ENVIO, EX.STATUS
FROM EXPORT EX 
WHERE EX.STATUS = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'
AND EXISTS (
           SELECT TMP.GSM 
           FROM EXPORT TMP 
           WHERE TMP.GSM = EX.GSM 
           GROUP BY TMP.GSM 
           HAVING COUNT(TMP.GSM) = 1)
```

Dessa forma, você exibe todos os resultados de GSM que são únicos (a subquery usa o HAVING COUNT pra garantir isso).
A ligação entre a query principal e a subquery é feita pelo GSM, usando o alias que utilizei nas queries.
Você pode entender melhor por aqui: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-exists/

Comment: muitooooooo obrigado, você literalmente salvou minha vida rsrs, vlw mesmo viu, pela atenção, funcionou legal aqui, eu tenho um outro filtro a ser feito você poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Having faz o que você precisa.

Este [link](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-having/) pode te ajudar

```
SELECT
 column_1,
 aggregate_function (column_2)
FROM
 tbl_name
GROUP BY
 column_1
HAVING
 condition;
```

Comment: Eu vi isso ontem mano, mas sou iniciante com Banco de Dados, eu fiz assim:

select gsm, status from export where status = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA' group by 1, 2 having count(gsm) = 1 order by 1;

Mas não sei se isso ta certo, ele até me retorna 234 dados, mas fica difícil saber pois a planilha tem mais de 3000 linhas